# Retrieve data from SQLite data base and display all data in a layout

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I created a SQLite data base in my android project which has the table "Book" containing columns id, isbn, title, resume. 
Iwant to retrieve isbn, title, resume for all the entries and display them in the layout of a fragment.

in fragment Books, the code line BookDAO livreBdd = new BookDAO(this); gives an error. I need to put a context but "this" doesn't work , "getActivity().getApplicationContext()" neither.

second thing, i will add data in the database and i will use the getAllBooks() method to retrieve all books in the database , each book with information "isbn", "title", and "resume" that i want to display in the layout of the fragment, i will have a List, how can i code this using SimpleCursorAdapter???

code of DataBaseHandler:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String BOOK_KEY = "id";
public static final String BOOK_ISBN = "isbn";
public static final String BOOK_TITLE = "title";
public static final String BOOK_RESUME = "resume";

public static final String BOOK_TABLE_NAME = "Book";
public static final String BOOK_TABLE_CREATE = "" +
        "CREATE TABLE " + BOOK_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
        BOOK_KEY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        BOOK_ISBN + " INTEGER, " +
        BOOK_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+
        BOOK_RESUME + " TEXT );";

public static final String BOOK_TABLE_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + BOOK_TABLE_NAME + ";";

public DatabaseHandler (Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version){

    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(BOOK_TABLE_CREATE);

}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(BOOK_TABLE_DROP);
    onCreate(db);
}

}
```

code of DAOBase:

```
public abstract class DAOBase {

protected final static int VERSION = 1;
protected final static String NOM = "data.db";

protected SQLiteDatabase mdb = null;
protected  DatabaseHandler mHandler = null;

public DAOBase(){
    super();
}

public DAOBase (Context context){
    super();
    this.mHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context, NOM, null, VERSION);
}
public SQLiteDatabase open(){
    mdb = mHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    return mdb;
}
public void close(){
    mdb.close();
}
public SQLiteDatabase getMdb(){
    return mdb;
}
}
```

code of BookDAO:

```
public class BookDAO extends DAOBase{
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Book";
public static final String KEY = "id";
public static final String ISBN = "isbn";
public static final String TITLE = "title";
public static final String RESUME = "resume";
public static final String TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " +
        TABLE_NAME + " (" + KEY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        ISBN + " INTEGER, " +
        TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
        RESUME + "TEXT );";
public static String TABLE_DROP = " DROP TABLE IF RXISTS" +
        TABLE_NAME + ";";

/*Add a book*/
public long insertBook(Book livre){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ISBN, livre.getIsbn());
    values.put(TITLE, livre.getTitle());
    values.put(RESUME, livre.getResume());
    return mdb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}

/*Update*/
public int updateBook(Book livre) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ISBN, livre.getIsbn());
    values.put(TITLE, livre.getTitle());
    values.put(RESUME, livre.getResume());
    return mdb.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY + " = ?", new String[]
            {String.valueOf(livre.getId())});
}

/*Delete a book*/
public int removeBookWithID(int id){
    return mdb.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY + " = ?" ,  new String[]
            {String.valueOf(id)});
}

/*Get all books*/
public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
    List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = mdb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Book livre = new Book();
            livre.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            livre.setIsbn(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            livre.setTitle(cursor.getString(2));
            livre.setResume(cursor.getString(3));
            bookList.add(livre);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return bookList;
}

}
```

code of Book:

```
public class Book {
private int id;
private int isbn;
private String title;
private String resume;

public Book(){

}

public Book ( int isbn, String title, String resume){
    super();
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.resume = resume;
}
public int getId(){
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
}
public int getIsbn(){
    return isbn;
}
public void setIsbn(int isbn){
    this.isbn = isbn;
}
public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}
public String getResume(){
    return resume;
}
public void setResume(String resume){
    this.resume = resume;
}

}
```

code of fragment Books and its layout when data should be displayed:

```
public class Books extends Fragment {


public Books() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_books, container, false);
    return v;

    BookDAO livreBdd = new BookDAO(this);

}

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.nabtech.android.nabilaffoauthor.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/booktitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="50" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bookisbn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="50" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bookresume"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="50" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the error? And which line caused it?

Comment: in fragment Books, the code line BookDAO livreBdd = new BookDAO(this); gives and error. I need to put a context but "this" doesn't work , "getActivity().getApplicationContext()" neither.                                                                   second thing, i will add data in the database and i will use the getAllBooks() method to retrieve all books in the database , each  books with information "isbn", "title", and "resume" that i want to display in the layout, i will have a List, how can i code this using SimpleCursorAdapter???

Comment: Please edit your question with that information

Answer (score 0):

> in fragment Books, the code line BookDAO livreBdd = new BookDAO(this);
>   gives an error. I need to put a context but "this" doesn't work

Use     `BookDAO livreBdd = new BookDAO(getActivity);`

**However, it cannot be after the `return` from the method, the code would not run, perhaps the real cause of the errors.**

However, you may wish to do this in the Fragment's `onCreate` method. (see below)

> second thing, i will add data in the database and i will use the getAllBooks() method to retrieve all books in the database , each book with information "isbn", "title", and "resume" that i want to display in the layout of the fragment, i will have a List, how can i code this using SimpleCursorAdapter???

1) Create a method, in the `BookDAO` class, that will return the extracted data as a Cursor e.g.

```
/*Get all books as Cursor*/
public Cursor getAllBooksAsCursor() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    return mdb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
}
```

2)

```
public class Books extends Fragment {

    BooDAO livreBdd;          //<<<< Added 
    ListView youlistview;     //<<<< Added
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA; //<<<< Added
    Cursor booklist;          //<<<< Added


    public Books() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    //<<<< onCreate Method Added
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        livreBdd = new BookDAO(getActivity); //<<<< first part of Question
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_books, container, false);
        //<<< All lines below added until return
        yourlistview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourlistview);
        booklist = livereBdd.getAllBooksAsCursor();
        mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, //<<<< see note1
            booklist,                            //<<<< source cursor
            new String[] {BookDAO,TITLE},        //<<<< column list see note1
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1},       //<<<< view list see note1
            0                                    //<<<< flags use 0
        );
        // Tie the adapter to the Listview
        yourlistview.setAdapter(mSCA);

        return v;

        //BookDAO livreBdd = new BookDAO(this); Can't have this after return.    
    }
}
```

Notes

- 1) The above example uses the build in layout that will display 1 item. However, you would likely want to specify your own multi-column layout. If so then you use the column list to specify the column names, as in the cursor, as additional elements to the string array. For each element in the column list there needs to be a respective element in the view list integer array that is the id of the view that will receive the data.
- The above is untested, so it may contain errors, it is intended as in-principle code.

Comment: thanks @MikeT, i followed your instructions. Now i have no errors. but when i open the app, it crashes... trying to figure out why :(